# Is there anyway to figure out a good estimate for sensor size for OpenCV?

Tags: opencv

I have extracted a camera calibration matrix using OpenCV and need to translate the focal length to mm.  It seems the easiest way to do this is through [calibrationMatrixValues()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#calibrationmatrixvalues).  For this, I need to supply the apertureWidth and apertureHeight which are actually the width and height of the physical sensor.  I took all my photos with the built-in "FaceTime HD" camera for the [Mid-2011 27" iMac](http://support.apple.com/kb/sp623).  I haven't been able to find any technical specifications for the camera.  While I've asked [Apple Stackexchange](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/84974/whats-the-aperture-or-sensor-size-for-a-facetime-hd-camera) for the exact sensor size, is there a way to move forward with any sorts of good estimates?

Answer (score 0):

If your camera can save jpg images, try to see the EXIF header if it contains what you search, and verify if it provide an accurate value.